# Xcode Preview and simulator crashing when referencing JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui

I have a json file on JSONbin.io, and it *was* working perfect. However, I've been fiddling around for hours with it and now for some reason when I start a live preview I get 'preview crashed', and in the simulator the app will simply crash/close when I try open the page drawing data from the JSON.

```
struct AccountPage: View {

    @State var posts: [Post] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(posts) { post in
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(post.barName)
                        Text(post.postCode)

                    }
                }
            }.onAppear {
                Api().getPosts { (posts) in
                    self.posts = posts
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above is the page that crashes, and the below is where the JSON file is decoded.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Post: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let barName: String
    let postCode: String
    let beerOne: String
    let beerPriceOne: String

}

class Api {
    func getPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "<JSON URL here>") else {
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(posts)
            }


        }.resume()
    }
}
```

When a crash occurs on the simulator, on line 26 of the second code snippet (let posts = try! ...) it gives the error:

```
"Thread 2: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:       Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))"
```

I'm sure it's a simple mistake as it was working perfectly previously, but I've been going over and over the problem and can't see the issue. All data types in the JSON are strings, and from what I can see it isn't pointing to a specific line in the JSON file.

Any pointers much appreciated!

Edit: As requested, I have added a sample of the JSON below (and issue persists even when using a JSON with only the below in it):

```
[
  {
    "barName": "The Joker",
    "postCode": "BN1 1XX",
    "dealOne": "241 on all cocktails, Mon-Thurs 7pm-9pm",
    "dealTwo": "Happy Hour Weekdays 2pm-3pm",
    "beerOne": "Stella Artois",
    "beerTwo": "Fosters",
    "beerPriceOne": "4.95",
    "beerPriceTwo": "4.35"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you post the JSON?

Comment: Don't use `try !`. Use `do/try/catch` and then you can `catch` the error and print it to see what is going wrong

Comment: Yeah, what Paulw11 said. It's trying to tell you exactly what the problem is, and you are stuffing cotton in your ears so you can't hear it. :)

Comment: @jnpdx I have added the JSON to the post:)

Comment: @Paulw11 catch sounds like a good idea for locating the issue, thank you. Sorry to bother you with more questions, but how would I use catch is this instance? I've not used it before and I'm none the wiser from googling it!

Comment: Use `if let data = data { do { let posts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data) } catch { print(error) } } else print("No data")}`

Comment: Also, that JSON isn't a great structure.  You should have an array of `Deal` strings and an array of `Beer` objects each with a name and price.